# How to show Products on carousel as like as images?

Tags: magento-1.9, products, html

Am using slick carousel,showing images on carousel like these

`<div class="my-class">
    <img src="">...</img>
  </div>`

and calling my-class on `custom.js`,Am showing Recently viewd products,cross-sell,up-sell on carousels.All works fine.

**How to show products with add-to-cart btn in carousel? Is these possible?**

**How to mark up Html for calling particular Product-ids to be shown on carousel?**

***Note*** : I spent more time on searching solution to my problem,But unfortunately no hints from our magento.stackexchange & Google.
Any ideas pls!!

Comment: did you try owl curosel

Comment: No,But whatever  carousel may be,Problem is how to mark up html for products to be called in carousel?